# Location to Call the function theme_uc_price($variables)

Tags: ubercart

This function is located at `/public_html/location/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_store`

```
function theme_uc_price($variables) {
  $output = '<span class="uc-price">' . uc_currency_format($variables['price']) . '</span>';
  if (!empty($variables['suffixes'])) {
    $output .= '<span class="price-suffixes">' . implode(' ', $variables['suffixes']) . '</span>';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

So my problem is, where can I find the ubercart file that calls this function? So I could get the computation where they add up the products so I could tweak it.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a theme function, based on DrupalContrib [theme_uc_price](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_store%21uc_store.theme.inc/function/theme_uc_price/7) it's called about 12 times within the Ubercart Suite.

As an example from one of the functions that calls the theme function which is [uc_object_attributes_form](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21ubercart%21uc_attribute%21uc_attribute.admin.inc/function/uc_object_attributes_form/7).

```
theme('uc_price', array('price' => $option->price))
```

That's how Drupal uses theme functions.